# R TwitteR : couldn't connect to host

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to download some tweets using TwitteR API when connected to my VPN, but the issue is that I keep on getting the couldn't connect to host error when doing the handshake.

I've tried several things like:

- Sys.setenv(http_proxy="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
- options(shinyapps.http = "internal")
- $options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
- h <- getCurlHandle(
  proxy         = "XXXXXX", 
  proxyport     = XXX,     cainfo = "cacert.pem")

But nothing seems to work, do you have any idea of what I can do to get it work?

Thanks in Advance.Code:

```
#Use below libraries:
require(twitteR)  #twitteR Lib
require(httr)     #httr Lib
require(ROAuth)

#Not Working
#Set Proxy so we can crawl twitter while connected to VPN
#Sys.setenv(http_proxy="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
#options(shinyapps.http = "internal")
#$options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
#h <- getCurlHandle(
#proxy         = "XXXXXX", 
#proxyport     = XXX,     cainfo = "cacert.pem")


l_consKey     <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
l_consSecret  <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

l_reqURL    <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
l_accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
l_authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"

#Download cacert.pm file
download.file( url = "http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile = "cacert.pem");

#Manage OAuth Authentication
twitCredentials <- OAuthFactory$new( consumerKey    = l_consKey
                                   , consumerSecret = l_consSecret
                                   , requestURL     = l_reqURL
                                   , accessURL      = l_accessURL
                                   , authURL        = l_authURL
                                   )
#Handshake
twitCredentials$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response. I already had both the library from github and the proxy option set. What I was missing was the setconfig option in my script:

Thanks a'lot!

Script:

```
###########################################################
#
# Libraries
#
###########################################################

library(twitteR);  # Twitter API
library(httr);     # httr library to set proxy options

###########################################################
#
# Variables
#
###########################################################

#Twitter API 
l_consKey     <-  yourConsumerKeyHere;
l_consSecret  <-  yourConsumerSecret;
l_token       <-  yourConsumerAccessToken;
l_tokenSecret <-  yourConsumerAccessTokenSecret;

#httr 
l_proxyUrl    <-  yourProxyUrl
l_proxyPort   <-  yourProxyPortNumber  


###########################################################
#
# Body
#
###########################################################


# Set proxy options
set_config( use_proxy( url  = l_proxyUrl
                     , port = l_proxyPort
                     )
          );

#OAuth authentication
setup_twitter_oauth( consumer_key     = l_consKey
                   , consumer_secret  = l_consSecret 
                   , access_token     = l_token
                   , access_secret    = l_tokenSecret 
);
```